# MenuProvider In Fragments Of Tabs

Tags: android, kotlin

i have MainActivity with drawer

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var appBarConfiguration: AppBarConfiguration
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        setSupportActionBar(binding.appBarMain.toolbar)

        binding.appBarMain.fab.setOnClickListener { view ->
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                .setAction("Action", null).show()
        }
        val drawerLayout: DrawerLayout = binding.drawerLayout
        val navView: NavigationView = binding.navView
        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main)
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
            setOf(
                R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_slideshow
            ), drawerLayout
        )
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
        navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
    }

    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main)
        return navController.navigateUp(appBarConfiguration) || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
    }
}
```

Drawer has three fragments attached Home, Gallery, Other

Home & Gallery has tabs and each tab had attached fragment,

**Home**

```
class HomeFragment : Fragment(), TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener {

    private var _binding: FragmentHomeBinding? = null

    // This property is only valid between onCreateView and
    // onDestroyView.
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        _binding = FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        val root: View = binding.root

        requireActivity().invalidateMenu()


        val tabLayout = binding.tabLayout
        val mViewPager = binding.viewPager

       val adapter = ViewPagerAdapter(requireActivity())

        adapter.addFragment(Fragment_HomeTab1(), "Tab 1")
        adapter.addFragment(Fragment_HomeTab2(), "Tab 2")
        adapter.addFragment(Fragment_HomeTab3(), "Tab 3")

        mViewPager.adapter = adapter
        mViewPager.offscreenPageLimit = 5

        TabLayoutMediator(tabLayout, mViewPager) { tab, position ->
            tab.text = adapter.getPageTitle(position)
        }.attach()

        tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(this)


        return root
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null
        requireActivity().invalidateMenu()
    }

    override fun onTabSelected(tab: TabLayout.Tab?) {

    }

    override fun onTabUnselected(tab: TabLayout.Tab?) {

    }

    override fun onTabReselected(tab: TabLayout.Tab?) {

    }
}
```

**Fragment_HomeTab1**
Fragment_HomeTab2 and Fragment_HomeTab3 is just like Fragment_HomeTab1, but each has its own layouts and menu like below

```
class Fragment_HomeTab1 : Fragment(), MenuProvider {

    private var _binding: FragHomeTab1Binding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!
    
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        _binding = FragHomeTab1Binding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        val root: View = binding.root

        requireActivity().addMenuProvider(this, viewLifecycleOwner, Lifecycle.State.RESUMED)


        return root
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        requireActivity().removeMenuProvider(this)
        super.onDestroyView()
    }

    override fun onCreateMenu(menu: Menu, menuInflater: MenuInflater) {
        menu.clear()
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.option_menu_home_tab_1, menu)
    }

    override fun onMenuItemSelected(menuItem: MenuItem): Boolean {
        if (menuItem.itemId == R.id.home_option_tab_1) {
            Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Home Tab 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            return true
        }
        return true
    }

}
class Fragment_HomeTab2 : Fragment(), MenuProvider {


    private var _binding: FragHomeTab2Binding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!


    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        _binding = FragHomeTab2Binding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        val root: View = binding.root

        requireActivity().addMenuProvider(this, viewLifecycleOwner, Lifecycle.State.RESUMED)

        return root
    }
    override fun onDestroyView() {
        requireActivity().removeMenuProvider(this)
        super.onDestroyView()
    }
    override fun onCreateMenu(menu: Menu, menuInflater: MenuInflater) {
        menu.clear()
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.option_menu_home_tab_2, menu)
    }

    override fun onMenuItemSelected(menuItem: MenuItem): Boolean {
        if (menuItem.itemId == R.id.home_option_tab_2) {
            Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Home Tab 2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            return true
        }
        return true
    }

}
```

**Gallery**

```
class GalleryFragment : Fragment(), TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener {

    private var _binding: FragmentGalleryBinding? = null

    // This property is only valid between onCreateView and
    // onDestroyView.
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {

        _binding = FragmentGalleryBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        val root: View = binding.root

        requireActivity().invalidateMenu()


        val tabLayout = binding.tabLayout
        val mViewPager = binding.viewPager

        val adapter = ViewPagerAdapter(requireActivity())

        adapter.addFragment(Fragment_GalleryTab1(), "Tab 1")
        adapter.addFragment(Fragment_GalleryTab2(), "Tab 2")
        adapter.addFragment(Fragment_GalleryTab3(), "Tab 3")

        mViewPager.adapter = adapter
        mViewPager.offscreenPageLimit = 5

        TabLayoutMediator(tabLayout, mViewPager) { tab, position ->
            tab.text = adapter.getPageTitle(position)
        }.attach()

        tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(this)


        return root
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null
        requireActivity().invalidateMenu()
    }

    override fun onTabSelected(tab: TabLayout.Tab?) {

    }

    override fun onTabUnselected(tab: TabLayout.Tab?) {

    }

    override fun onTabReselected(tab: TabLayout.Tab?) {

    }
}
```

**Fragment_GalleryTab1**
Same as Home Tab's Fragments

**
Home: Tab 1, Tab 2, Tab 3
Gallery: Tab 1, Tab 2, Tab 3
**

Everything is working fine until i change Fragment from Home to Gallery using drawer
As soon as i change from home to gallery, everything stop working, menu list updates to gallery's tab's menu but onMenuItemSelected for the selected tab on gallery never fires.

When i switch back to Home from Gallery, gallery's tab's menu is still visible on home's tab in option menu and when i select from option menu, nothing happen.

Please help me out.

I tried everything, but nothing works.